# GMail doesn't mark up email html (sending via PHP)

Tags: gmail, html

I am trying to send a html email via mail(), however gmail just displays the email as plain text, no mark up, eg:

```
mail("blah@blah.com", "<i>Italic Text</i>");
```

just appears as

```
<i>Italic Text</i>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This question would probably get better answers on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set your email headers?

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

If yes, do any other email clients have the same problem? Or is it just Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with css, the *i* tag is deprecated, not sure if that is causing it...

```
<span style='font-style:italic;'>Italic Text</span>
```

Or you could try using the em tag:

```
<em>Italic Text</em>
```

.

Comment: Semantic Markup (what you're describing) won't make any difference whatsoever here.  And FWIW, using HTML 1, non-semantic tags still work just fine.  Luckily, Microsoft doesn't own the web, so things are actually backwards compatible on HTML.

Comment: @bpeterson76 Email HTML support has nothing to do with web HTML compatibility. These are two *very* different things. It never hurts to try multiple approaches and see which the email client in question will render propertly.